# how to write a python program that can tell whether the numbers entered can form a triangle or not?

Tags: python, if-statement, testing, error-handling, logic

i was writing the following code:

```
def form_triangle(num1,num2,num3):

    success="Triangle can be formed"
    failure="Triangle can't be formed"

    if(num1 < num2 + num3):
        if(num2 < num1 + num3):
            if(num3 < num1 + num2):
                return success
        
    else:
        return failure


num1=3
num2=3
num3=5
result = form_triangle(num1, num2, num3)  
print(result)
```

but the problem is this code is unable to pass all the test cases. for instance, if num1, num2, num3 have values 1, 2, 3 respectively, then the expected output should be N/A but my output is None. so, what changes should i have to made in my code to have the expected output.

Comment: With 1, 2 and 3, you get a flat triangle, where 3 = 1 +2 (and not 3 < 1+2). So just change your comparisons to `<=` instead of `<` to account for such cases.

Comment: Also, your `else` only runs if the first condition is False. You want it to be executed if any of them is false, so either rewrite the `if` part as `if num1 <= num2+num3 and num2 <= ...`, or remove the `else` completely, so that `return failure` gets executed in any case if you don't reach the first `return`.

Comment: Isn't None the functionality you want? Python doesn't have N/A unless you explicitly define it with a string or something.

Answer (score 0):

use multi condition `if statement` as follows

```
def form_triangle(num1,num2,num3):
    success="Triangle can be formed"
    failure="Triangle can't be formed"
    if(num1 < num2 + num3) and (num2 < num1 + num3) and (num3 < num1 + num2):
        return success
        
    else:
        return failure
num1, num2, num3 = 1,2,3
result = form_triangle(num1, num2, num3)  
print(result)
```